# Notation and semantic for approximation?

Tags: notation, approximation

Likewise the notation $\approx$ that says is "approximately equal to.." is there a symbol for the meaning "is approximately less of..."? What's the formal meaning of such symbols?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in LaTeX, but yes - just replace the underbar in $\leq$ with a squiggle and that's it. It is used when you have bounds, but the bound is more conveniently expressed as an approximation. We used it when we did numerical error analysis using Taylor approximations, and also when something is bound by a random variable that is approximated by a normal or something.

Edit: found the LaTeX command, it's '\lesssim':

$f(x)\lesssim C \Leftrightarrow f(x) \leq C \pm \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is comparatively small and might even vanish asymptotically.

Comment: I don't get anyway if in a formal proof it could have sense to use it. Order relationship are based on the well order properties, but can a simbol like an approx inequality have sense in a formal proof context?

Comment: I would guess that it's not usually used in proofs. I've only seen it in the context of applied mathematics - coding theory, numerical analysis, statistics... But then again, $\approx$ isn't used in proofs either. You definitely could use it as a 'shorthand' for bounds that are approximate in the finite case but tight in the asymptotic case: for example $f(n) \leq C \pm \epsilon(n)$, when $\epsilon(n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lesssim\text{or} \gtrsim $$